# inline-block and block in list

Tags: html, css

Okay I am a newbie regarding CSS and while during a tutorial I got completely lost.
As far as I know a block element takes up a whole line. And an inline element only takes up the width and height of the element and an inline-block works like an inline element but here you can set width and height.

Okay and now the question. In the tutorial it makes an unordered list:

```
header nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
}
```

There are 5 elements in the list. Now 4 of the elements is text like "Menu", "Contact us" etc. but one element in the list should be the logo image. Now to add the logo I need to do this:

```
header nav ul li#logo a:link {
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 260px;
background: url('images/logo.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

But what I don't get is that I first make the elements in the list to inline-block elements (which makes sense cause I want them next to each other and one of them is an image.) But why in the world do I have to turn the element in the list that I want to contain the logo image into a block element? First of all I thought it would take up the whole line (but the elements are still next to each other) and second, I already turned the elements in the list into inline-block elements? Anybody who know the answer?

Comment: If you append an `<img src="images/logo.png">` instead of a background image, probably would work as you expect

Comment: Using background, you leave that element empty, and empty elements usually are sizeless, they would disappear...

Comment: Thanks but the code above is working. But I need to write either:        
header nav ul li#logo a:link {
display: block;                                                                                                                     or                                                                                                                                      header nav ul li#logo a:link {
display: inline-block;                                                                                                    For it to work.

Comment: There's always more ways to achieve the same goal... Choose what you understand most

Answer (score 1):

Considering the few points below you should get it why the anchor has `display: block`

1- The `display:block` is set to the `anchor` which is inside the `li`... not directly to the `li` itself.

Thats why its still showing all `li` next to each other because you changed one of the inner elements inside it to `block` not the `li` itself.

2- The default `display` property of anchor is `inline` ... this means that you don't have control on `width` and `height`.

3- To be able to show `background-image` inside `anchor` you will have to set a specific `width` and `height` and thats why the display is changed from `inline` to `block` to be able to control `width` and `height`

BTW you can also use `inline-block` with the anchor and it will work